# Laravel/OVH very slow response time for 5 simultaneous sencha requests

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I install an empty laravel4 framework on my pro OVH hosting.
When, I launch 5 simultaneous request on the public 'hello world' page, I only get one quick answer, the four others can take more than a minute !

It works fine on my local wamp system !
Do you know if there is an OVH limiation or a LARAVEL pb ?

Regards

EDIT : 
Hello,

Find the solution.
The new Laravel4 'native' session driver causes slow response time for simultaneous request !
Changed by 'cookies' driver works fine.

Comment: That's interesting - what limitation does the hosting have which causes that issue? I haven't run into that before.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to create a ticket to OVH support, because it's not very normal that native session driver cause slow reactions.
Are you on a dedicated server or a shared hosting ?